# Олимпидная задача на С++

Tags: c++, алгоритм

День добрый. Прошу, помогите с задачей. Условие ниже:

> Вова большой любитель оригами. Для складывания бумажного самолетика ему понадобилось сложить гармошку размера 1 на 1 из листа клетчатой бумаги размера N на M. Сгибать бумагу Вова может только по линиям разлиновки. Например, если  N = 3, a M = 1, то последовательность действий для сгиба выглядите так:
> [image: пример]

> Выведите минимальное кол-во сгибов для получения гармошки.

Есть 2 примера ввода - вывода:

> INPUT 
> 2 2 
> OUTPUT
> 2

> INPUT
> 5 3
> OUTPUT
> 5

Вот мой код, на нем все три теста проходят(плюс банальный тест 1 1), а вот дальше - никак.

```
#include <string>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
typedef long long ll;
int main(){
    ll h, w; cin >> h >> w;
    if(h == 1 || w == 1){
        cout << max(h, w) - 1 << endl;
    }
    else{
        ll a = h, b = w;
        ll c1 = 0, c2 = 0;
        while(a != 1){
            if(a % 2){ a--; c1++;}
            else{a /= 2; c1++;}
        }
        c1 += (b - 1);
        while(w != 1){
            if(w % 2){w--; c2++;}
            else{w/=2; c2++;}
        }
        c2+=(h-1);
        cout << min(c1, c2) << endl;
    }
}
```

По ограничениям: N <= 1000 >= M;

Comment: А что считать-то надо? Или надо еще и догадаться по ответам, что считать? :)

Comment: @Harry Оу, дико извиняюсь, сейчас исправлю

Comment: Есть какой-то URL проверяющей системы? не хотелось бы давать какие-то варианты, не проверив..

Comment: Нельзя однозначно понять, что такое тут гармошка, но попробуйте ответ ceil(log2(n)) + ceil(log2(m))